# Interpolate Temperature Using DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dem, interpolation

I want to "co-interpolate" temperature with DEM. I have SRTM 90m aggregated to 1km and I want to "co-interpolate" my DEM with points with temperature data. How do I do this? I am using ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'co-interpolate'? This is a new term for me.

Comment: this sounds like a something you can solve with co-kriging http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Understanding_cokriging but you will need geostatistical analyst to do it in ArcGIS

Comment: @radouxju: Yes, I think this what I want. But when I was trying to do this, and I am a newbie on this, so many things were asked. Can you help me on this?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: Basically, I want an interpolated temperature raster that reflects elevation as well.

Comment: How big is your area? If it's fairly small, temperature will be likely show a significant negative correlation with elevation so a simple regression of temperature and elevation from your weather stations  will give you an equation you can use in the raster calculator.

Comment: Seems like the solution really is to perform Co-kriging.

Comment: I know that you are the OP who posted this question, but more context would be useful for users who come to this question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you mean is Co kriging your temperature data based on a DEM. 
What you need:
-Shapefile of points with temperature data
-DEM of your study area

You need to have the geostatisical analyst tool (see customize, toolbars). Open de geostatisitcal wizard in this toolbar. You can now choose kriging/co-kriging. You need to select two datasets. So the first is you shapefile with temperature points and the second is the DEM. In the following tabs you can adjust many parameters (try optimize model, upper right corner, tab 3. or check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUcGDgPVcTA .

Also check out this esri page: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_a_map_using_cokriging .

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will suffice but; If you have 3D analyst you can interpolate your temperature raster independently then drape it over the DEM and visualize in 3D in ArcScene. This way you could analyze the heat data in relation to elevation.  Alternatively, you could generate a hillshade raster from your DEM and either overlay the hillshade model over your heat raster and make the top raster semi-transparent or to preserve colour intesity combine the hillshade and the heat raster using Image Analysis Function technique described [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/03/08/an-alternative-to-overlaying-layer-tints-on-hillshades/). 
You can also use the Image Analysis function result to drape over the input DEM in ArcScene which will make the hillshade component of the Image Analysis Function layer more pronounced while still preserving the colour intensity of the heat raster.